# Android group same view type inside a card using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there another way how to group elements of `RecyclerView` with the same `view type` inside a card? As an example, I want to achieve something like in Revolut. What I've read until now is to use a list inside a `recycler view`, but I am not sure about the performance, I might show more than 10 000 items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Happy that I managed to do it.

If anyone is interested in how I managed to pull this off, I just created a `recycler view` with two view types and the one with the "transactions" I made it a card with a negative margin-top. Basically I have set marginTop to -16dp so the card corners don't overlap. Caution, you need to set a bigger margin if the corner radius is bigger than 8 (I used 8)

I will answer happily on the questions

Good luck implementing it.